# How to calculate difference in proportion of three different categories between two groups(column) in gtsummary in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

In my dataset, I have a binary categorizing variable gender (categoreies: "male"/"female"). I wanted to calculate the proportion difference along with 95% CI between each category of ses_status(categories "low"/"middle"/"high") between male and female. I've tried the code below which provided proportion difference for just binary variable smoke(categories "yes"/"no") but not for ses_status having 3 categories.

##### Dataset

```
 dt<-data.frame(gender=as.factor(rep(c("M","F", "M"), 10)),
                     smoke=as.factor(rep(c("Yes","No"),15)),
                     ses_status=as.factor(rep(c("low", "high","middle"),10))
                     )
```

Sample code that I've tried

```
dt%>%
   tbl_summary(by=gender,
                  include = c(ses_status, smoke)
                  )%>%
  add_difference(include = c(ses_status, smoke))
```

How to calculate the proportion difference for each category between two groups using gtsummary?

Comment: Can you add reproducible data?

Comment: @Maël I've added sample dataset to the question.

Comment: @BikramAdhityaAdhikari did you see my response below? Does that help ?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a working dataset for us next time, either your dataset (using the command `dput()` and copy and paste it the result on the forum here, or provide a mock dataset.

I am unfamiliar with the `gtsummary()` command, but you can answer this using a generalized linear model `glm()` with a `family=binomial` distribution

Here is an example with three treatment levels, as you have presented here.

```
dt <- structure(list(Y = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Treat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Run a `glm()` and Look at the model summary

```
model <- glm(Y ~ Treat, family="binomial", data=dt)
summary(model)
```

from here, you simply need to reverse transform the summary output with the `exp()` command, and since we know 1.96 * standard error (se) = our 95% CI, we can calculate both the upper and lower CI.

Here is how you could do it "Treatment B" in my provided example:

```
exp(0.8473-0.4418)/(1+exp(0.8473-0.4418))
exp(0.8473-0.4418+0.9449)/(1+exp(0.8473-0.4418+0.9449)) # upper 95% CI
exp(0.8473-0.4418-0.9449)/(1+exp(0.8473-0.4418-0.9449)) # lower 95% CI
```

And it's done! :)

Comment: @bikram : Did you understand my response? It should work for what you want to do

Comment: It worked well. I created a function and integrate the result into table from gt_summary.